# is it possible to use heyzapp mediation sdk with flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, heyzap, fyber

I'm a new developer, and want to know if is it possible to use heyzapp-fyber mediation SDK in my flutter/dart apps ?

Or if there is any alternative mediation network that already support flutter/dart i would be thankful for that information.